# Am I creating too many mysqli objects?

Tags: php

Each time I create a mysqli object, i use a prepared mysqli statement like this (sometimes several per page):

```
$update_foobar_statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE foo SET bar  = ? WHERE foobar = ?");
$update_foobar_statement->bind_param('ss', $bar, $foobar);
$update_foobar_statement->execute();
```

I'm essentially creating a copy of the mysqli object. This had me thinking that I might be creating too many objects and hurting my web apps' overall performance.

I like clarifying what the mysqli statement is doing through the initial variable, but is this bad practice? Should i be doing the following instead?

```
$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE foo SET bar  = ? WHERE foobar = ?");
$mysqli->bind_param('ss', $bar, $foobar);
$mysqli->execute();
```

Comment: if you are intantiating mysqli class everytime you want to query than you are creating multiple objects.. if you instantiated $mysql = new mysqli(...) only once anf use that variable.. you just just using one object...

Comment: also you can force the single object creating by creating singleton class for database ..

Answer (score 0):

You would also have to store the return value of `$mysqli->prepare` also in the second case, so the only thing remaining under discussion is the name of the variable and if you will be reusing it or not.

It doesn't really matter in the bottom line. Memory-wise using a separate variable for each query could theoretically result in higher requirements, but that would have no practical effect until you get into the tens of thousands at the very least. So don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

if is always the same sql you can just do that part again:

```
$update_foobar_statement->bind_param('ss', $bar, $foobar);
$update_foobar_statement->execute();
```